# Copying MongoDB Database into Local Machine

Tags: mongodb, localhost, local, database

I have a MongoDB database that resides on a remote server machine whose IP address is 192.168.1.20 on a local network. For development and testing purposes, and since I am not allowed to modify or delete the database on the server for security purposes, I want to copy the database on my local machine for my personal use.

Can anyone please tell me, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [copy database](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands) command which I guess should be good fit for your need.

```
db.copyDatabase("DATABASENAME", "DATABASENAME", "localhost:27018");
```

Alternatively, you can just stop MongoDb, copy the database files to another server and run an instance of MongoDb there.

---

**EDIT 2020-04-25**

Quote from MongoDB documentation

> MongoDB 4.0 deprecates the `copydb` and the `clone` commands and their mongo shell helpers `db.copyDatabase()` and `db.cloneDatabase()`.
>
> As alternatives, users can use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` (with the `mongorestore` options `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo`) or write a script using the drivers.

Reference [here](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/copydb-clone-deprecation)

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Where exactly do I run this command? Sorry for sounding like a noob as I am a rookie in MongoDB and have just been learning it from the past 24 hours.

Comment: in terminal, first start mongo in terminal then execute these command

Comment: I get ```/* 1 */
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "unauthorized"
}```

Comment: Please check credentials and roles

Comment: {
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "not master",
  "code": 10107
} error

Comment: I think it's better to use mongodump for this

Comment: And how we can copy local database to mongo AWS  ec2 instance? I have a Node app hosted in ec2 and I have used Bitnami MEAN.

Comment: MongoDB 4.0 deprecates the copydb and the clone commands and their mongo shell helpers db.copyDatabase() and db.cloneDatabase(). See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#copydb-and-clone-commands

Answer (score 44):

I do this by creating a dump of the remote db to my local machine, which I then restore:

1. **Make sure you have a mongo instance up and running** (eg. run `mongod.exe` from your bin folder in a terminal window. On my windows computer that's C:\mongodb\bin)
2. **Make a dump from remote db**: Open a new terminal window, move to the bin folder again, run:

   `mongodump -h example.host.com --port 21018  -d dbname --username username --password yourpass`

   *(Change the parameters to suit your own situation.)*
3. **Restore the dumped database:** Once the dump has been made, run the following command so that you have a local db:

   `mongorestore -d theNameYouWantForYourLocalDB dump\nameOfRemoteDB`

   *(replace nameOfRemoteDB with the name of the remote db, the same as in previous command, and replace theNameYouWantForYourLocalDB with the name that you want your new local db to have)*

Comment: Best way to do.
The db.copyDatabase() didnt copy data and skip some collections.
I'm working with small vm, and one just for mongo.
I cant dump from these vm and doing it from my computer with this:
`mongodump -h 00.00.00.00 -d nameOfRemoteDB
mongorestore -h 00.00.00.00 -d nameOfRemoteDB ./dump/db`
is the best manipulation.

Comment: Do you know how will it work with a database that has replica sets?

Comment: The first part of this answer was helpful, so +1. I'm new to Mongo. I get this error when trying the mongorestore step: `The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}` https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#examples

Comment: Just to complete the answer I had to set `--authenticationDatabase admin` as indicated on this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32013726/3123338)

Answer (score 9):

This should be a comment to the answer of @malla, but I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm posting it here for other's reference.

In step 2, When you are trying to dump file from a remote server, remember to add out option so that you can restore locally later: (in my first try, I didn't add it and it failed, saying dump\db_name was not found).I'm not sure whether my way efficient or not. But it worked for me.

**Step 2:**

```
mongodump -h example.host.com --port 21018  -d dbname --username username --password yourpass --out <path_you_want_to_dump>
```

**Step 3:**

```
mongorestore -d theNameYouWantForYourLocalDB \<path_you_want_to_dump> + nameOfRemoteDB
```

Answer (score 1):

The mongoexport command:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/

Or, mongodump command:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

Answer (score 1):

mongodb has commandline tools for importing and exporting. Take a look at `mongodump --collection collection --db test` and `mongorestore --collection people --db accounts dump/accounts/`

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongodump/
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongorestore/

this even works over the network

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) command to copy the database to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

### Server to local machine

Use the ssh command to connect to your remote server:
`ssh user@serverip`

Once you are logged in to the server, use the mongodump command to create a backup of your database:

`mongodump --db dbname --out backupdir`

To copy the backup from your server to your local system using the "scp" command, you can follow these steps:

`scp -r user@serverip:/path/to/backupdir /path/to/localdir`