# Can't create backup mongodump with --db. Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodump

When I create backup of all databases in MongoDB (version 3):

```
mongodump --username bacUser --password 12345
```

It's OK. But when I try to create backup of a selected db:

```
mongodump --username bacUser --password 12345 --db test
```

It gives me this error:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.

Answer (score 140):

work with this:

```
--authenticationDatabase admin
```

mongodump and mongorestore commands need the name of database where mongodb user's credentials are stored. (thanks @Zubair Alam)

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why this is a solution?

Comment: mongodump and mongorestore commands need the name of database where mongodb user's credentials are stored.

Comment: usually the credentials are stored in the same database I want to backup/restore, am I wrong?

Comment: @Nate if you don't specify authenticationDatabase, mongodump will use the database you want to back up as authentication database. If the user you are authenticating as belongs to other database than the one you want to back up, you will get authentication error

Comment: This answer works for me, full command is like this:  `mongodump -u admin -p pwdxxx --authenticationDatabase admin  -d mydb -o mydb_backup`

Answer (score 36):

This should work.

```
mongodump -h SERVER_NAME:PORT -d DATABASE_NAME -u DATABASE_USER -p PASSWORD
```

Also this error can popup if username or password are wrong.

Comment: this worked for me thanks, as many suggested executing mongodump with authenticationDatabase param does not work for me

Comment: This simplified command worked perfectly.  I tried the other options of using --authenticationMechanism and --authenticationDatabase setting the correct values but continued to get issues with authentication failed.

Answer (score 19):

```
mongodump --host <host-ip> --port 27017 --db <database>  --authenticationDatabase admin --username <username> --password <password> --out ./Documents/
```

After all the trail, I found above working command to dump from mongdb.

Answer (score 7):

```
mongodump --collection coll_name --db DBname  -u UName -p *** 
          --authenticationDatabase <admin/privileged> --host ip  
          --port portNo  --out foldName
```

Answer (score 7):

```
mongodump   --authenticationDatabase admin -uroot -pyourpassword
```

here root is username and yourpassword is your password.

This command will backup/dump all database back-up in current directory.

Answer (score 5):

for dump and restore

```
mongodump --db nameDatabase --username userName --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --out mongodb\
mongorestore --db nameDatabase --username userName --password password --authenticationDatabase admin <path backup> --drop
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. This answer would be clearer if you added a little explanation/commentary. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you still get same error with --authenticationDatabase admin  , than probably your username and password are incorrect.
Try adding a user db.createUser() , with appropriate role ( i gave write permission as well)

than run below command : (ignore -h if you are running on local)

```
 mongodump -h <ip>:<port_number> -d db_name -u newUser -p newPassword -o /home/mongodump/
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: mlabs has an online utility to create new users as well. the new user worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The following steps worked for me on MongoDB 3.2:

1. Check of course if your admin username and pw are correct. You can do this with the mongo shell:

mongo

use admin
db.auth("admin", "yourpassword")

If this returns 1, the password is correct.

2. Then add the role "backup" to your admin (or make sure this role is already added).
   db.grantRolesToUser("admin", [{ role: "backup", db: "admin" }])
3. Finally, the mongodump command. It did not work for me when I tried to pass the password as an argument. Instead do this:

mongodump --username admin --authenticationDatabase admin --db yourmongodatabase

Then add your password when it promts for it.

This works for me...

Comment: It's critical that user has an appropriate role: backup or root

Comment: This happened to me too, only when I remove the password and then type it on next line, it worked. The problem was because I had special characters then I had to use single quote instead of double quote... thanks @adeel for his answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `mongodump` was not correctly processing the password. The solution was to escape the password literal.

This did not work:

`mongodump -p my$password -o <output directory>`

This did work:

`mongodump -p 'my$password' -o <output directory>`

Answer (score 2):

Use signle Quotation around password. if you are using any special character in your password. That will solve your issue. Use following command.

mongodump  -d database_name -u userName -p 'password' --out directory_name

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `--uri` option, you need to add [`authSource=admin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource) as a parameter to your connection string (assuming your user is on the admin database)

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://user:pass@host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/?replicaSet=rs0"
```

Becomes:

```
mongodump --db=test --uri="mongodb://user:pass@host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&authSource=admin"
```

Answer (score 2):

userAdminAnyDatabase is not enough to do mongodump on all the dbs that's why you are getting this error. You will need a super user that has:

```
userAdminAnyDatabase
readWriteAnyDatabase
clusterAdmin
```

privileges to run mongodump on all dbs.

OR you just need 'backup' privilege

```
db.grantRolesToUser('username', [{
  role: 'backup',
  db: 'name of ur authentication db'
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem when trying to dump my database info from mLab.
It was happening because I had mongo `2.x` locally and `3.x` in mLab. 
Upgrading my local mongo to the same major version as mLab allowed me to do the dump, thus solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mLab then it could be the version in your local mongo is not match with mLab. By default, Ubuntu will install mongo `v2.x` and mLab is `v3.x`. You could check with this command:

```sh
mongo --version
```

**Install new mongo version:**

1. Remove your old local mongo (***be careful, it may remove all your local database***)

```
sudo apt remove mongo-clients mongodb
```

2. Import the public key used by the package management system.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv D68FA50FEA312927
```

3. Create a list file for MongoDB.

   - Ubuntu 14.04

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

- Ubuntu 16.04

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

4. Install the MongoDB packages

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

**Now you can dump** your database with this command:

```
mongodump -h <host>:<port> -d <database-name> -u <user> -p <password> -o <output directory>
```