# Mongo DB: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, shell, authentication, debian

I have 2 problems. First I can't login into my MongoDB. I tried this way: [Can't create backup mongodump with --db. Authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993168/cant-create-backup-mongodump-with-db-authentication-failed) but no succsess. I've tried differnt passwords and user, but I can't log in. My Mongo Server runs on an Debian 8 Server. For Uninstall and install, I used this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ . I start the debian new after every uninstall.

Can I remove the password. In the conf data, I comment auth = true. I hope you can help me.

I get this message

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2016-06-29T12:30:01.079+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

Answer (score -1):

No authentication by default on mongo that might have to do with system privileges.

Comment: How I can check it

Comment: Stupid I know. Sorry. Now I need only a connection

Comment: Please check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372684/mongodb-3-2-authentication-failed